# install router to meteor js

Tags: meteor, terminal, router

I`m new in meteor js. I have a question how should I install router to meteor js, in Mac Os, it installs: mrt add router, but how should I install in windows terminal, I want to add it in my project.

Thanks)

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://www.meteor.com/install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your terminal, within your application folder, do

```
meteor add kadira:flow-router
```

and read the documentation to see how you can use the router.

https://atmospherejs.com/kadira/flow-router

> Carefully Designed Client Side Router for Meteor.
>
> FlowRouter is a very simple router for Meteor. It does routing for client-side apps and does not handle rendering itself.
>
> It exposes a great API for changing the URL and reactively getting data from the URL. However, inside the router, it's not reactive. Most importantly, FlowRouter is designed with performance in mind and it focuses on what it does best: routing.

Comment: Your welcome @NuriddinZuhirxojaev. Also since SO is a Q&A platform, you should mark my answer as correct, by clicking on the checkmark right next to it.